# How would you test your ui/ux design decision in the fastest and cheapest way?

Tags: gui-design, ux-field, usability-testing

I was at this interview for ux designer position and my interviewer asked me that if your colleagues didn't agree on your design, how would you defend it?

Then I said I would test the design in cheapest and fastest way. Then he was like "how would you do it?"

I said ask people to test it. But he was like "that's not cheap!".

What you think?

Comment: What do you mean by "ask people to test it"?  Do you mean hire someone else to test your design and then provide the results to your colleagues?

Comment: Well, I meant asking the closet persona around to our target audience, in this case we were looking at teenagers, could be colleague's kids, I should have elaborated for him maybe. @Stephen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Print out the screen on plain white paper using a color printer.
2. Put the paper in an opaque folder.
3. Walk out to the desk of the lowest tech person in the office.
4. Ask them to look at something for you.
5. Open the folder, facing them... count to five... close the folder.
6. Then, with all your colleagues within earshot, have the lowest tech person in your office describe what the screen is for and what they would be able to do with it.

Comment: That is absolutely brilliant. I do something similar with my wife. Whenever I have a design that has no money for UI testing, I usually ask her to critique it for me

Comment: That is really clever, thank you for your unique answer @Henry ,but what if the target audience is very different from the people in the office, in this case we were looking at teenagers between 11-18. Again Thanks :)

Comment: Good point.  Some products do have very specific user-bases which may be hard to sample cheaply.  If however, you are writing a product for such an audience, I would hope that you at least know a few of targets.  You may have to drive across town to run your test, but it is always worth it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [UsabilityHub](https://usabilityhub.com/)? Its tests allow you to expose a living person to your design, and after five seconds they're asked various questions about it. You can also make flow tests, where they're asked to navigate through your design, or tests where they decide which version looks better.

It's *cheap* - it has a free plan, where you "pay" for your tests with credits earned through taking other users' tests (which doesn't take too much time). The downside would be the *fast* thing. On the free plan you get the lowest priority, meaning you might have to wait a while to get meaningful results. However, you could just send your friends a link to your test and ask them to take it.

Overall, it's pretty much the same as Henry Taylor's way, but it's more digital.

Comment: thank you, that is a very good solution too, I also thought of MechanicalTurk, but never used it.

Answer (score 1):

Testing is as expensive as you want to make it.

Pay for usability consultants and participant compensation, sure that would start to become expensive.

Take interactive or paper prototypes to a local cafe and shout a few participants a free coffee. Cheap in comparison.

It always comes down to what you are looking to test (fidelity, complexity, etc) and who you need to test with (niche audiences are harder to stumble upon).

Comment: No offense Devin, but this seems like a random and amateurish "methodology".  Are his colleagues going to feel any better knowing that a handful of coffee shop patrons felt a certain way about his designs?

Comment: When you’re dealing with consumer tech, the users in the café are the same people who would be invited into your usability study. Once you’re comfortable with carrying out testing sessions I believe you could carry out an effective session in a public place. After all, [you only need 5 people to gather great insights.](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/why-you-only-need-to-test-with-5-users/)

Now if you were testing a control interface for plane pilots for example, then yes, a brief test using café patrons is not going to suffice, as the both the context and the audience are not a good fit.

Comment: Would that work with paper prototypes or screen mock-ups?

Comment: I imagine you could run a paper session or a digital one in that scenario.

Comment: Do you think that would work with airline pilots?

Comment: No I don't suspect though, in a case where the design is critically tied to a specific niche user audience, you would be best to screen participants and seek out those in that profession, e.g. pilots.

That said, if there was a cafe at the local pilot academy, you might be able to carry out some more relaxed testing with pilots during their breaks. Unless the design specifically required for them to be in a particular emotional state, e.g. high alert levels while flying a plane, in which case this approach may not work well at all.

Comment: Do you have any experience at all with the operation or design of advanced avionics?

Comment: None at all. I there is some confusion here, the point was not to debate the nuances of testing aviation technology, it was simply to highlight that a niche design like that would not benefit from such broad, informal testing. An interface for pilots was simply plucked from the air as an example of something on the other extreme of the spectrum to generic consumer tech. Let's end this line of discussion as it has veered off topic.

Comment: Shoestring/hallway usability testing is a perfectly acceptable methodology, so suggesting that the OP visit a cafe is an acceptable answer. There's no need to be rude, Stephen (prefacing rudeness with "no offense" is not an excuse), nor is there any need to get caught up in an extended argument in these comments.

Comment: @Rahul That is up to the hiring manager or management to decide.  I would encourage OP and anyone who reads these posts to be prepared to provide a professional and workable answer when questioned about their preparation and methods.  Please don't go into an interview and suggest you can test complex and critical path equipment by catching a group of pilots on break.